# Use python 3 in reticulate on shinyapps.io

Tags: python, r, shiny, reticulate

I have some code in Python 3 which I'm running in R through the `reticulate` library to use in a `shiny` app. It works fine in my local machine, but when I published in shinyapps.io reticulate is using Python 2 by default.

So far I tried to use `use_python` function, but I'm not sure about the path:

```
use_python("/usr/bin/python3", require = TRUE)
```

The logs give me the error:

```
2019-02-12T13:44:54.691167+00:00 shinyapps[710102]: Warning: Error in initialize_python: Python shared library '/usr/lib/libpython3.5.so' not found, Python bindings not loaded.
2019-02-12T13:44:54.697101+00:00 shinyapps[710102]:   64: stop
2019-02-12T13:44:54.697103+00:00 shinyapps[710102]:   63: initialize_python
2019-02-12T13:44:54.697104+00:00 shinyapps[710102]:   62: ensure_python_initialized
2019-02-12T13:44:54.697105+00:00 shinyapps[710102]:   61: py_run_file
2019-02-12T13:44:54.697106+00:00 shinyapps[710102]:   60: source_python
2019-02-12T13:44:54.697107+00:00 shinyapps[710102]:   59: server [/srv/connect/apps/str_telefonica/app.R#57]
2019-02-12T13:44:54.697385+00:00 shinyapps[710102]: Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : 
2019-02-12T13:44:54.697387+00:00 shinyapps[710102]:   Python shared library '/usr/lib/libpython3.5.so' not found, Python bindings not loaded.
```

Comment: I think this is the standard Linux path: `use_python("/opt/python/Python-3.7.1/bin/python3.7")`

Comment: Did you ever succeed in getting this to work?
I am struggling with it as well..

Comment: I don't think I did

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To deploy an app to shinyapps.io using `reticulate` and Python 3, your code should create a Python 3 virtual environment and install any required packages into it:

```
reticulate::virtualenv_create(envname = 'python3_env', 
                              python = '/usr/bin/python3')

reticulate::virtualenv_install('python3_env', 
                               packages = c('numpy'))  # <- Add other packages here, if needed
```

Then, instead of using the `use_python()` function, just point `reticulate` to the Python 3 virtual environment that you created:

```
reticulate::use_virtualenv('python3_env', required = T)
```

For a more complete tutorial on deploying a Shiny app using `reticulate` with Python 3 to shinyapps.io, check out [this step-by-step example](https://github.com/ranikay/shiny-reticulate-app).

**Note**: Until a few months ago, `reticulate` invoking `virtualenv` from Python 3 still created a Python 2 virtual environment by default. However, [this was fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/commit/0a516f571721c1219929b3d3f58139fb9206a3bd) in the development version of `reticulate` as of Oct 8, 2019.

You can install that particular version of `reticulate` with the fix by using the R package `remotes`:

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/reticulate", force = T, ref = '0a516f571721c1219929b3d3f58139fb9206a3bd')
```

or use any `reticulate` >= v1.13.0-9001 and you'll be able to create Python 3 virtual environments on shinyapps.io.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. Can I ask why you put virtualenv_create/install into server.R instead of .Rprofile? Still learning shiny. Thanks!